Seemingly under-estimated backtest performance of intraday trading
Suppose I have an intraday strategy that is flat at the beginning of the day and flat at the end of the day. I run the backtest and generates thousands and thousands of trades over say one year. Obviously, many parameters-decisions have to be made for the backtest:
A transaction cost estimate ( entering and exiting ) number in basis points needs to be used of course. Also, vague approximations of how much can be bought while balancing market impact. Things like, how long does it take to get in and at what price. Similarly, how long does it take to get out and at what price ? The whole thing is just one big vague estimate. No doubt about it.
And then there are all the parameters associated with the trading strategy itself. thresholds, flags, Z-scores, stop-loss amts, volatility estimates and all sorts of other things. If you get a poorly performing backtest, you can probably change enough things to eventually make it look good. At the same time, if you don't try to trick yourself, you can tell by specific statistcs whether the thing is working or not. Anyway, that's getting off the track.
The one thing that's special about intraday in my eyes is that one can get flat during bad market periods by shutting the whole process down for the day. At whatever time XXX that it looks like it's gonna be a "non-noise filled day", get out of everything and enforce that there is no more trading for the day. This would improve performance of a backtest because I can see, by looking at it, that a lot of times its poor days rather than poor specific stocks.
Clearly, there's no way to put the "shut it off" ability in a backtest so it seems like the backtest performance will be consistently under-estimated. Am I missing something here ? Thanks for any wisdom or references. I've never run an intraday trading strategy in real life so I could definitely use any kind of wisdom.
                                                   Mark


If you can quantify a condition that determines the "bad market periods" (eg. surveilling the intraday P&L per trade and observing whether this is lower or near the cost of running or defining a risk-limit that when breached, makes sure the algo exists the market until the next day), then you can also put it into a backtest. This backtest will better reflect the P&L of your alternative trading strategy. You can even count the days where it exits the market and investigate whether this is to your liking.

yeah. that's an interesting solution. I'd have to think about the best way or even if there is a way to do that. thanks.

Pleb: I thought about your solution and looked at my code. Given the current infrastructure ( i.e. the code ), a lot of R code would need be to be changed in order to check the pnl constantly during the day. Definitely it's possible though with a significant change in the infrastructure. I'll probably just leave it alone for now and then mention your idea if someone asks. But it's something to think about for the future. Thanks.

Note that, although my backtester is ill-equipped to do what you mentioned, production systems calculate a current PNL for the day so it wouldn't be a problem to put it in a production system.
